# Changing multiple columns of all lines that meet a search criterion

Tags: regular-expression, search, replace

There are lots of posts about how to search and replace a single column of a file, using `\%Nc` syntax. I want extend this syntax to replace multiple columns in all lines that meet some criterion. For example,

```
PWITHDRAWAL BY EFTPOS 0240331 BWS
PEFTPOS DEBIT 0000409 GROUNDS
PEFTPOS DEBIT 0074959 ASQ INTE
PWITHDRAWAL BY EFTPOS 0510811 COLES
PWITHDRAWAL BY EFTPOS 0043699 XIAN
```

I need to modify columns 23-29 (the columns with numbers) on each line containing `WITHDRAWAL BY EFTPOS`. Obviously there are lots of ad hoc ways to do this.   For example,
`g/PWITHDRAWAL BY EFT/s/\%23c/X` will change column 23 in the three selected lines to `X`.   I could repeat the command for each column that needs changing, but there's presumably something like  `g/BY EFT/s/\%23c-\%29c/X/` that would do it in a single command.

Could anybody advise please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there's presumably something like g/BY EFT/s/\%23c-\%29c/X/ that would do it in a single command.

23-29 is the same as 7 columns/chars starting from 23.

```
g/WITHDRAWAL BY EFT/s/\%23c.\{7\}/XXXXXXX
```

If it's guaranteed to be the first 7-digit number in the string "WITHDRAWAL" you can change it to:

```
g/WITHDRAWAL BY EFT/s/\d\{7\}/XXXXXXX
```

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping for, thanks very much

Comment: could also use something like this: `/\%>22c.\%<30c` to restrict matching from column 23 to 29.